# Force logout ALL users at a certain time

Tags: users, logout

I'm wondering if it's possible to logout all users 2 times a day using the function wp_logout() ?

I see loads of plugins who can logout idled users but we want to log out every single users twice a day at

2PM and 10PM

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/348483/118534

Comment: @Tim that answer gives some of the question but it doesn't fully answer this or the other question either

Comment: Good point Tom, I didn't spot that it was only using `wp_logout()`. it should be possible to log out everyone by deleting all the session data from the database. `WP_Session_Tokens::drop_sessions()` is provided for this purpose. I'll write a solution below.

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible, WordPress provides the [WP_Session_Tokens](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_session_tokens/) class to manage logged in sessions. Then it's just a matter of connecting it to the cron. The following is a simple plugin file which I think should do it. Add it to the plugins directory and it should start working. *not tested.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Logout Users
Description: Forces all users to be logged out twice a day.
Author: Tim Ross
Version: 1.0.0
Author URI: https://timrosswebdevelopment.com
*/

/**
 * Create hook and schedule cron job on plugin activation.
 * Schedule recurring cron event.
 */
function logout_users_plugin_activate() {
    $timestamp2pm = strtotime( '14:00:00' ); // 2:00 PM.
    $timestamp10pm = strtotime( '22:00:00' ); // 10:00 PM.
    // check to make sure it's not already scheduled.
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'logout_users_plugin_cron_hook' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( $timestamp2pm, 'daily', 'logout_users_plugin_cron_hook' );
        wp_schedule_event( $timestamp10pm, 'daily', 'logout_users_plugin_cron_hook' );
        // use wp_schedule_single_event function for non-recurring.
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'logout_users_plugin_activate' );


/**
 * Unset cron event on plugin deactivation.
 */
function logout_users_plugin_deactivate() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'logout_users_plugin_cron_hook' ); // unschedule event.
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'logout_users_plugin_deactivate' );

function logout_all_users() {
    // Get an instance of WP_User_Meta_Session_Tokens
    $sessions_manager = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance();
    // Remove all the session data for all users.
    $sessions_manager->drop_sessions();
}

// hook function logout_users_plugin_cron_hook() to the action logout_users_plugin_cron_hook.
add_action( 'logout_users_plugin_cron_hook', 'logout_all_users' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this issue myself by deleting the usermeta from the database directly by doing as follows:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key=\'session_tokens\'');
```